# How to limit selection to x successive slots

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar in my first web app. What I'd like to do is to make a selectConstraint that would allow selection of x successive slots but not x+1. E.g it would be possible to select 4*30 minutes times but not 5*30 minutes anymore. Is there a easy way to do this? Other option would be to allow selection but then unselect ones which go over this but it's not very nice..

Comment: What is slotDuration? And how many slot do you want to select at a time?

Comment: 30 minutes / slot. At max 4 slots can be selected

Comment: Then, you need to make some patches in fullcalendar.js. Which version of fullcalendar do you use?

Comment: I'm using latest official version. So there is no way to make it with selectConstraint?